# How can I make big multiline comments of equations passages?

Tags: equations, comments, multline

I tried to make clear explanations of some passages in this formula on the right side of the equations, but there's always something that goes wrong (I mean that I don't aesthetically like the result). Can you help me?

This is my latest try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \eta &=\frac{W}{F(\rho_M)-F(\rho_M')}=\frac{W}{F(\rho_M)-F(\rho_S')-F(\rho_A')}=  &\textrm{\parbox{8em}{from point 4. of the list above,}} \\
     &=\frac{F(\rho_W')-F(\rho_W)}{F(\rho_M)+F(\rho_S')+F(\rho_W')-F(\gamma_{SW},H')-F(\rho_S')}=  &\textrm{\parbox{8em}{from the equality  between point 3. and 4.,}}\\
     &=\frac{F(\rho_W')}{F(\rho_W')-F(\gamma_{SW},H')}= & \textrm{\parbox{8em}{from point 1.  $F(\rho_M)=F(\rho_W)=0$,}}\\
     &=\frac{1}{1-\frac{F(\gamma_{SW},H')}{F(\rho_W')}}  & \textrm{\parbox{8em} {obtained by dividing numerator  and denominator by $F(\rho_W')$.}}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I would use a top-aligned `\parbox` and put it in a macro, so you can change all at once if you decide to change the appearance.  Also, `\raggedright` helps avoid wide inter-word space in narrow columns.  The `\textrm` is not needed to wrap the `\parbox`.  I would also ditch the trailing `=` at the end of each math line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\newcommand\mynote[1]{\parbox[t]{8em}{\raggedright#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \eta &=\frac{W}{F(\rho_M)-F(\rho_M')}=\frac{W}{F(\rho_M)-F(\rho_S')-F(\rho_A')}  &\mynote{from point 4. of the list above,} \\
     &=\frac{F(\rho_W')-F(\rho_W)}{F(\rho_M)+F(\rho_S')+F(\rho_W')-F(\gamma_{SW},H')-F(\rho_S')}  &\mynote{from the equality  between point 3. and 4.,}\\
     &=\frac{F(\rho_W')}{F(\rho_W')-F(\gamma_{SW},H')} & \mynote{from point 1.  $F(\rho_M)=F(\rho_W)=0$,}\\
     &=\frac{1}{1-\dfrac{F(\gamma_{SW},H')}{F(\rho_W')}}  & \mynote{obtained by dividing numerator  and denominator by $F(\rho_W')$.}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For example, adding `\footnotesize` to the `\mynote` macro yields the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here are three possibilities. I defined an `\eqnote` command, which displays its text in `footnotesize`and has an optional width (default 0.32\linewidth):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand{\eqnote}[2][0.32\linewidth]{\parbox{#1}{\footnotesize\upshape\RaggedRight#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    η& =\frac{W}{F(\rho_M)-F(\rho_M')} = \frac{W}{F(\rho_M)-F(\rho_S')-F(\rho_A')} & \eqnote{from point 4. of the list above,} \\
         & =\frac{F(\rho_W')-F(\rho_W)}{F(\rho_M)+F(\rho_S')+F(\rho_W')-F(\gamma_{SW},H')-F(\rho_S')} & \eqnote{from the equality between points 3. and 4.,} \\
         & =\frac{F(\rho_W')}{F(\rho_W')-F(\gamma_{SW},H')} & \eqnote{from point 1. $F(\rho_M)=F(\rho_W)=0$,} \\
         & =\frac{1}{1-\frac{F(\gamma_{SW},H')}{F(\rho_W')}} & \eqnote{obtained by dividing numerator and denominator by $F(\rho_W')$.}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{3}
    & \qquad & η&=\frac{W}{F(\rho_M)-F(\rho_M')} = \frac{W}{F(\rho_M)-F(\rho_S')-F(\rho_A')} &\quad & \eqnote{from point 4. of the list above,} \\
    & & &=\frac{F(\rho_W')-F(\rho_W)}{F(\rho_M)+F(\rho_S')+F(\rho_W')-F(\gamma_{SW},H')-F(\rho_S')} & & \eqnote{from the equality between points 3. and 4.,}\\
    & & &=\frac{F(\rho_W')}{F(\rho_W')-F(\gamma_{SW},H')} & & \eqnote{from point 1. $F(\rho_M)=F(\rho_W)=0$,}\\
    & & &=\frac{1}{1-\frac{F(\gamma_{SW},H')}{F(\rho_W')}} & & \eqnote{obtained by dividing numerator and denominator by $F(\rho_W')$.}
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\begin{flalign}
  && η&=\frac{W}{F(\rho_M)-F(\rho_M')} = \frac{W}{F(\rho_M)-F(\rho_S')-F(\rho_A')} & & \eqnote{from point 4. of the list above,} \notag\\
  & & &=\frac{F(\rho_W')-F(\rho_W)}{F(\rho_M)+F(\rho_S')+F(\rho_W')-F(\gamma_{SW},H')-F(\rho_S')} & & \eqnote{from the equality between points 3. and 4.,}\notag\\[-2ex]
  \\[-1ex]
  & & &=\frac{F(\rho_W')}{F(\rho_W')-F(\gamma_{SW},H')} & & \eqnote{from point 1. $F(\rho_M)=F(\rho_W)=0$,}\notag\\
  & & & =\frac{1}{1-\frac{F(\gamma_{SW},H')}{F(\rho_W')}} & & \eqnote{obtained by dividing numerator and denominator by $F(\rho_W')$.}\notag
\end{flalign}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try with `varwidth`, so the maximum really needed width will be used.

The command `\eqnote` has an optional argument for the maximum allotted width, see the difference in the two cases (the default 8em is used for the first case). Some more vertical space between the lines seems necessary.

I'd remove the trailing equals signs, because they would be distracting (and aren't usually employed).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newcommand{\eqnote}[2][8em]{%
  \begin{varwidth}{#1}
  \raggedright\footnotesize
  #2
  \end{varwidth}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\eta &=\frac{W}{F(\rho_M)-F(\rho_M')}=\frac{W}{F(\rho_M)-F(\rho_S')-F(\rho_A')}
     &&\eqnote{from point 4. of the list above,}\\[1ex]
     &=\frac{F(\rho_W')-F(\rho_W)}{F(\rho_M)+F(\rho_S')+F(\rho_W')-F(\gamma_{SW},H')-F(\rho_S')}
     &&\eqnote{from the equality  between point 3. and 4.,}\\[1ex]
     &=\frac{F(\rho_W')}{F(\rho_W')-F(\gamma_{SW},H')}
     &&\eqnote{from point 1.  $F(\rho_M)=F(\rho_W)=0$,}\\[1ex]
     &=\frac{1}{1-\frac{F(\gamma_{SW},H')}{F(\rho_W')}}
     &&\eqnote{obtained by dividing numerator  and denominator by $F(\rho_W')$.}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\eta &=\frac{W}{F(\rho_M)-F(\rho_M')}=\frac{W}{F(\rho_M)-F(\rho_S')-F(\rho_A')}
     &&\eqnote[10em]{from point 4. of the list above,}\\[1ex]
     &=\frac{F(\rho_W')-F(\rho_W)}{F(\rho_M)+F(\rho_S')+F(\rho_W')-F(\gamma_{SW},H')-F(\rho_S')}
     &&\eqnote[10em]{from the equality  between point 3. and 4.,}\\[1ex]
     &=\frac{F(\rho_W')}{F(\rho_W')-F(\gamma_{SW},H')}
     &&\eqnote[10em]{from point 1.  $F(\rho_M)=F(\rho_W)=0$,}\\[1ex]
     &=\frac{1}{1-\frac{F(\gamma_{SW},H')}{F(\rho_W')}}
     &&\eqnote[10em]{obtained by dividing numerator  and denominator by $F(\rho_W')$.}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]